# Why does /**[newline] not always insert the Javadoc template including @param and @return in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm documenting code in Eclipse and have been using the /** followed by Enter a lot to insert the Javadoc template. However this does not always work for some reason, it will create the template for writing comments but it won't automatically insert the @param and @return text. If I copy the exact same method to another class it will insert the full template.

It would be a big help if anyone could tell me why it won't do this in some situations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know this usually happens when Eclipse doesn't know for sure which method you want to document.

A more reliable way would be to select the method/class etc. you want to create the JavaDoc for and press ALT + SHIFT + J or right click on the method in the class outline and clicking Source -> Generate element comment.

Comment: Hitting this shortcut will point me to the interface that this class implements (i.e. it inserts (non-Javadoc) and then a line with @See package.class#method(params), I guess it doesn't like Javadoc being added to a class that implements an interface.
So if for some reason I do want to document the implementation of an interface, I guess I'll have to do it manually. I realize that might not be the best way to approach documentation but I was just wondering why it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Well the whole point of methods described by an interface is, that the interface already includes all the
documentation necessary (and the implementing methods shouldn't behave any different than what the
interface specifies). I would put additional information in the javadoc class header.

Comment: I just found another example in a class that isn't extending or implementing anything. No idea why it doesn't work with /** here but alt-shift-j does insert the javadoc template correctly.

Comment: Typing `/**` then pressing `Enter` key just above your method's name will also auto-trigger `ALT+SHIFT+J`.

Answer (score 1):

It always works for me UNLESS there's a comment above the method I'm trying to add the documentation for. Here's an example of some code and an undocumented method where it wouldn't work:

```
public class Test {
    // Declare some fields. Bla bla bla.

    // ~ Constructors

    public Test() { // <-- If I insert /** above this line it fails to work
    }
}
```

My fix is usually to temporarily declare a variable that separates my method from the comments so the Eclipse recognises what I'm doing...

```
public class Test {
    // Declare some fields. Bla bla bla.

    // ~ Constructors
    int i;
    public Test() { // <-- If I insert /** above this line it works. Then discard the temp var.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This started happening with me occasionally with the last build, Mars.  Restarting Eclipse fixes it.  It seems that I really need to restart Eclipse every day in order to avoid random problems like this.